# Node js exits after an error thrown to catch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

When there is an error in the Json file, after calling this function Nodejs exits and closes the server.

```
function LoadAPConfig() {
    try {
        var data = fs.readFileSync('./Settings/APconfig.json');
        APSettings = JSON.parse(data);
        SavedAPSettings = APSettings;
        console.dir(APSettings);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('There has been an error parsing AP JSON file.')
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

But I only want to show the error and continue the rest of the program. What I need to do here?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show full code?

Comment: Do you see the log messages from the `error` block? If not, I suspect that the crash might happen in a different part of your code that you have not shared in your question.

Comment: I think that may be right and the code crashes some where else. This is a multifile code and many parts may not have errored catcher. I there a way to show all errors in all files in console and the continue to the rest of the code?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the `try` block is being executed by putting a `console.log("try block entered")` at its beginning.